# Como passar string para uma função de inserção

Tags: c, c++

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<string.h>

struct lista{

    char nome[20];

    int idade;

    struct lista* prox;

};

typedef struct lista Lista;


Lista* lst_cria(){

    return NULL;

}

Lista* lst_insere(Lista* lst, int id, char name[], int n){

    
    Lista* Nlst=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));

    Nlst->nome; 

    Nlst->idade=id; 

    Nlst->prox=lst;

    return Nlst;

    
}

void lst_imprime(Lista* lst){
    
    Lista* p;
    
    for(p=lst; p!=NULL; p=p->prox){

        printf("%s",p->nome);

        printf("\n");

        printf("%d",p->idade);

        printf("\n");

        
    }
    
    
}






main(){

    Lista* nova_lst;

    nova_lst=lst_cria();

    nova_lst=lst_insere(nova_lst,29,"lucio",20);

    nova_lst=lst_insere(nova_lst,27,"diego",20);

    lst_imprime(nova_lst);

    
    
    
}
```

Olá, não sei como passar uma string para ser inserida via função. os números imprimem, mas os nomes não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Você escreveu:**

```
    Lista* Nlst=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));

    Nlst->nome; 

    Nlst->idade=id; 
    Nlst->prox=lst;
    return Nlst;
```

**E pretendia escrever provavelmente**

```
    Lista* Nlst=(Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));

    Nlst->nome = nome; 

    Nlst->idade=id; 
    Nlst->prox=lst;
    return Nlst;
```

Entenda que uma Lista é um conjunto de nós. E cada nó tem um payload, uma carga de dados, que em geral é um simples ponteiro.

Quando você junta tudo na estrutura do nó como fez aqui vai ter muito mais trabalho e menos resultado. A Lista é um container. É até chamada assim em C++, ou collection em java.
Então a Lista tem metadados. Controles que deveriam ficar DENTRO da Lista e não soltos pelo programa.

Compare sua estrutura com essa abaixo e imagine se seu programa ficaria ou não mais fácil de controlar, em especial se tiver umas 3 listas no mesmo programa...

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[20];
    int idade;

}   Item;

typedef struct st_node
{
    Item*           D; // dado
    struct st_node* N; // adiante
    struct st_node* P; // atras

}   Node;

typedef struct lista
{
    unsigned    size;
    unsigned    limite;
    Node*       inicio;
    Node*       fim;

}   Lista;
```

Entenda que nesse caso

- se mudar o dado não precisa mexer na Lista ou no Node. Só muda o Item.
- algumas questões se resolvem de imediato: cada lista tem DENTRO dela seu tamanho e seus ponteiros.
- aqui cada Node tem uma carga de dados
- a lista tem nodes e nada fala sobre dados

Por exemplo em seu programa a própria rotina que insere um nó tem os campos DOS DADOS como argumento. Assim fica tudo amarrado e se mudar um tem que mudar tudo...

```
    Lista* lst_insere(Lista* lst, int id, char name[], int n);
```

Quando poderia ser

```
    Lista* lst_insere(Item* item, Lista* lista);
```

E assim se logo mais colocar o telefone em Item nada muda. Se trocar Item por aquela lista de livros do exercício seguinte nada muda... ;)
Deste modo até onde a lista se preocupa a rotina que insere insere um nó na lista. nada mais. nunca mais.

Entenda que a primeira função que você escreve não é a que insere mas sim a que lista os elementos. A lógica? Simples: você vai precisar listar para testar, e a função que lista tem que funcionar para uma lista vazia ou inexistente. Então escreva antes essa e a que apaga a lista. Depois a que insere nós...

**Nota:** no geral, usar ponteiros apenas para um lado na lista só complica as coisas e não simplifica nada. Tudo o que for fazer com a lista vai implicar em voltar para o início e se reposicionar. Toda hora. Como em geral se usa  a lista para navegar, digamos, numa lista, já imagina o que acontece: numa fila para voltar uma posição tem que contar onde está e voltar para o início e contar de novo. Numa playlist, o exercício clássico, para voltar a música não dá, e assim por diante: tudo fica mais complicado e lerdo.